# net_rim_cldc not found

Tags: blackberry, java-me, mobile, rim-4.5

I am getting error as : module net_rim_cldc not found while debugging application on real device.

I am using device Pearl 8100 with v4.5.0.81 
and
eclipse JDE plugin with component pack 4.5.

I have read on forum that if there is difference between device software and development ide then this error occur, but i am using same versions.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when debugging on a device for which you don't have .debug files. The .debug files are only available for OS versions that are released with simulators. To take full advantage of debugging on a real device, you have to load the same OS version that you have JDE and simulators for.

On the other hand, if you have properly developed and debugged your application on the simulator, having an OS mismatch is not a huge problem. you can still use the debugger to track down most problems.

Comment: For the application that im running, when application reaches at one point it terminates suddenly...Is that related to this ?
Because I have tried debugging,breakpoints,try-catches,printlns...When I run app. with JDE and not eclipse, at app termination point an exception is displayed as "unknown(net_rim_cldc)...wht can be done?

Comment: What is the class name of the exception thrown? What do you mean by the app termination point?